# How to obtain the client local socket port from MySQL JDBC driver?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tcp, port

I have a Java application where I connect to a mySQL Server with `"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`.

After the connection is established, I need the  Client local port. This means the port the Java application receives data from the MySQL Server.

Is there a way to receive it in my own source code, after I established the connection?

I tried all the information in `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData`.

Comment: Transient information about a socket is not database metadata. What do you need for?

Answer (score 0):

For the [MySQL Connector/J there's sources on github](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/MysqlIO.java).

The actual Socket that connects to the MySQL Server is defined in `MysqlIO` as

```
public Socket mysqlConnection = null;
```

The class `ConnectionImpl` contains a getter for that:

```
public MysqlIO getIO() throws SQLException
```

So if you manage to cast your `Connection` to `ConnectionImpl` (haven't checked that yet), you could do:

```
ConnectionImpl impl = (ConnectionImpl)con;
Socket sock = impl.getIO().mysqlConnection;
int localPort = sock.getLocalPort();
```

Good Luck.